# What is the importance of LastWriteTime.Ticks

Tags: c#, .net

I have 9 xml files which is our project database, we are writing in to database by this method
i am giving only bit of code.

```
  public int WriteDatabase(string path)
      {
lock(m_spoData)
            {
          m_spoData.DataVersion.Rows.Clear();
          SpoConfigData ds = new SpoConfigData();

               ds.ExternalApplication.Merge( m_spoData.ExternalApplication );
               ds.WriteXml( path + ExtAppFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.SpoServer.Merge(m_spoData.SpoServer);
               ds.ManagedObject.Merge( m_spoData.ManagedObject );
               ds.AttributeValue.Merge( m_spoData.AttributeValue );
               ds.Threshold.Merge( m_spoData.Threshold );
               ds.WriteXml( path + ObjectFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.ObjectClass.Merge( m_spoData.ObjectClass );
               ds.ObjectAttribute.Merge( m_spoData.ObjectAttribute );
               ds.WriteXml( path + ClassFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.Image.Merge( m_spoData.Image );
               ds.AlertImageList.Merge( m_spoData.AlertImageList );
               ds.WriteXml( path + ImageFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.ManagedGroup.Merge( m_spoData.ManagedGroup );
               ds.WriteXml( path + GroupFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.UserZone.Merge( m_spoData.UserZone );
               ds.ViewFolder.Merge( m_spoData.ViewFolder );
               ds.ViewGroup.Merge( m_spoData.ViewGroup );
               ds.ZoneMgGrpCollection.Merge( m_spoData.ZoneMgGrpCollection );
               ds.WriteXml( path + ZoneFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.ResourcePolicy.Merge( m_spoData.ResourcePolicy );
               ds.ResourceType.Merge( m_spoData.ResourceType );
               ds.ResourceObject.Merge( m_spoData.ResourceObject );
               ds.ResourceAttrValue.Merge( m_spoData.ResourceAttrValue );
               ds.WriteXml( path + ResourcePolicyFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.Principal.Merge(m_spoData.Principal);
               ds.Role.Merge( m_spoData.Role );
               ds.WriteXml( path + RoleFile );
               ds.Clear();

               ds.Permission.Merge( m_spoData.Permission );
               ds.WriteXml( path + PermissionFile );
               ds.Clear();} }
```

her down side two line of code is there like this

```
// reset data version base on file last write time.
               m_spoData.DataVersion.AddDataVersionRow( ( new FileInfo( path + ZoneFile ) ).LastWriteTime.Ticks );
```

If i changed ZoneFile to PermissionFile  what will be the impact here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code is using [`LastWriteTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx) - which is a numeric value representing the time the file was last written to -  as some kind of versioning mechanism. Since you write both files (PermissionFile and ZoneFile) around the same time I wouldn't expect any major difference.

Comment: But there is some impacts,,thats the one which i want to know

Comment: @Peter: The only difference will be that the last write time of PermissionFile will be passed to `AddDataVersionRow` the rest depends on the behavior of that method which you haven't shown - if you do not detail what exactly your problem is that's all I can say.

Comment: kindly check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066301/how-to-check-version-mismatch-during-reconnect